# printf(%d) printing a very big integer

Tags: c, integer, printf

I did this simple function to print the content of an array of int.

```
void print_array(int size, int array[size])
{
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("%d}\n", array[size - 1]);
}
```

It seems to work fine with examples. However, while using it to debug a function, I got the result :

```
{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 16, 17, 18, 8, 0, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27, 28, 9, 30, 31, 21, 24, 14, 24, 25, 26, 27, 19, 31, 41, 33, 23, 33, 34, 35, 27, 28, 29, 50, 808779818, -363075840, -202888522, 45, 46, 0, 0, -1377617600, 32767, -1377617208, 32767, 2055390135, 22066, 2055404888, 22066, 448540736, 32670, 446392223, 32670, 16, 48, -1377617632, 32767, -1377617824, 32767, -363075840, -202888522, 448540736, 32670, 32670, 0, 284, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1377617929, 32767}
```

As you can see, some of the numbers here are too big to be printed as int, even though I used the %d identifier in the printf function.
Can someone explain to me what happens here ?
When I'm testing the equality of this array with the good answer, the test happen to be true (???).

I tried understanding it by doing

```
    int a = 808779818;
    int b = 42;
    assert(a == b);
```

but there the assert fails.

Comment: The maximum number in the posted values is `2055404888`. The minimum one is `-1377617929`. Both of them can fit in signed 32-bit integer. Why do you think "too big to be printed as int"?

Comment: okay I mixed up bits and bytes but now I need to figure out how my assert test is not failing. Thank you

Comment: If `int` is 32 bits, `808779818` is within the range of `int`. If `int` is 16 bits (which is legal but rare except on small embedded systems), then storing `808779818` in an `int` *might* result in a value of `42` but only if the conversion discards the high-order bits, which is common but not guaranteed. On such an implementation, `808779818` is of type `long int`, and the conversion yields an implementation-defined result.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, some of the numbers here are too big to be printed as
> int

You can easily check what is maximum and minimum integer value in your system:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("int: %d  %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("short int: %hd  %hd\n", SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("char: %hhd  %hhd\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    printf("long int: %ld  %ld\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    printf("long long int: %lld  %lld\n", LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/az7nd8fEP

> ```
> int a = 808779818;
> int b = 42;
> assert(a == b);
> ```

From man pages:

> ```
>    If expression is false (i.e., compares equal to zero), assert()
>    prints an error message to standard error and terminates the
>    program by calling abort(3).  The error message includes the name
>    of the file and function containing the assert() call, the source
>    code line number of the call, and the text of the argument;
>    something like:
> ```

> but there the assert fails.

And it is expected result as `808779818 != 42`